# Grep and ignoring leading whitespace

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

I've been working on a bash script to search for names of defines, and then grab the hex values for them and put them in the list. Once I have the list of names I'll attempt to search for "#define [name]" using -w to ensure exact match, and then awk '{ print $3 }' to grab the hex value.

However it works if the line in the header file is similar to

```
a.h:#define [name] 0x0001
```

But it does NOT work if it is similar to

```
a.h:    #define [name] 0x0001
```

How can I get around this? I have tried this

```
grep -nrw "\s*#define[[:space:]]*$p" . --include=*.h | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

I thought the `\s*` would ignore the leading whitespace before `#define` but it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you need to use extended grep or the `-E` flag to use `\s`

Comment: I am, but I believe the issue comes from leading white space causing `#define` to be shifted from $1 to $2

Comment: You should describe the problem better, it is hard to understand what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @ryekayo thank you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `awk` (using `grep` seems redundant to me, since `awk` already can match a regular expression):

```
awk '$0~/\s*\#define\s*\[.*\]\s*.*/ {print $3}' *.h
```

Going through the expression in more detail:

```
$0 ~ /regexp/          # look for the regular expression in the record
      \s*              # whitespace, any number of times
         \#define      # literal string, '#' has to be scaped
                 \s*   # same as above
                    .* # any character, any number of times, this is
                       # your hex code and you can refine the regex here
{ print $3 }           # print the third field if the record matches
```

To have this run recursively, e.g.

```
mkdir -p a/b/c
echo "   #define [name] 0x0001" > a/a.h
echo "   #define [name] 0x0002" > a/b/b.h
echo "   #define [name] 0x0003" > a/b/c/c.h
tree
.
└── a
    ├── a.h
    └── b
        ├── b.h
        └── c
            └── c.h

3 directories, 3 files
```

since `awk` needs to be given a list of files to operate on, you could:

```
find . -type f -name "*.h" \
  -exec awk '$0~/\s*\#define\s*\[.*\]\s*.*/ {print $3}' {} \;
0x0002
0x0003
0x0001
```

Comment: can this handle recursive as well? (checking *.h from subdirs)

Comment: Very well done, this is awesome. Based on some suggestions and testing I have found that `grep -Ro '#define\s*\(.*\)' *.h` works. -o was tricky to get the entire line but if you just tell it to include anything that comes after, I can now just use awk to get element 3. since grep includes the header file name, if there was a space before `#define` it would mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -o` to print only the matching part of the line.

Obviously take the `\s` part out again, because you don't want that part.

Comment: Problem is that with -o, now I don't get the hex value since it only grabs `#define` and `$p`